# How to draw a simple sine, square, sawtooth waveform in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I would like to draw a simple waveform in LaTex.
However, I have the `sine wave` only, if possible but in `dotted line` like the example below.

[image]

I have the basic MVE as below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{(sine wave)
        \label{fig:Simple pure tone (sine wave)}
    }{%
        \resizebox{.45\textwidth}{.3\textwidth}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                        declare function={%
                        f1(\x) = 1.2*sin(2.5*deg(\x)); f2(\x)=0.6*(1.2*sin(2*deg(\x ))+1*sin(4*deg(\x))+1.2*sin(6*deg(\x)));
                    }
                ]
             \begin{scope}[local bounding box=T]
               \draw[latex-latex](0,2)  node[above]{} |- (8,0) ;
               \draw plot[domain=0:7,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] ({\x},{f1(\x)});
              \end{scope}

             \path foreach \X in {T} {(\X.east) node[below] {}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Its output:

[image]

Comment: `\draw plot[samples at={0,90,...,900}] (\x/100,{sin(\x)});` for the triangle, the rest you can for example use `plot coordinates {(x1,y1)(x2,y2)...}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is not working. `\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}[

\draw plot[samples at={0,90,...,900}] (\x/100,{sin(\x)});]

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
             `

Comment: Why have you put the `\draw` in the optional argument to the `tikzpicture`? Remove the `[` and `]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you mean `\begin{figure}[h!]
\draw plot[samples at={0,90,...,900}] (\x/100,{sin(\x)});
\end{figure}
             `

Comment: No, there you've remove the entire `tikzpicture`. I meant `\begin{tikzpicture} \draw plot[samples at={0,90,...,900}] (\x/100,{sin(\x)}); \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks. But there is no `dotted horizontal line` there

Comment: Obviously not, that was just the triangle wave, nothing more. `\draw [densely dotted] (0,0) -- (9,0);`. I'll probably add an answer in a bit though,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this. I don't have time for much explanations right now, but ask if there is anything you don't understand.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]

\foreach \y in {0,...,4}
     \draw [densely dotted] (0,-3*\y)  -- +(6,0);

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=sine]
  \draw plot[domain=0:6,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))});
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm, local bounding box=square]
  %\draw (0,0) |- ++(1,1) |- ++(1,-2) |- ++(1,2) |- ++(1,-2) |- ++(1,2) |- ++(1,-2) |- ++(0,1);
  % the above line does the same as the following one, but without the foreach loop
  \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,2,3}  {|- ++(1,1) |- ++(1,-2) -- ++(0,1)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm, local bounding box=ramp]
  %\draw (0,0) |- ++(0.25,1) |- ++(1.75,-1) |- ++(0.25,1) |- ++(1.75,-1) |- ++(0.25,1) |- ++(1.75,-1);
  % the above line does the same as the following one, but without the foreach loop
  \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,2,3} {|- ++(0.25,1) |- ++(1.75,-1)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-9cm, local bounding box=sawtooth]
  %\draw (0,-1) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,-2) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,-2) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,-2);
  % the above line does the same as the following one, but without the foreach loop
  \draw (0,-1) foreach \x in {1,2,3} {-- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,-2) };
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm, local bounding box=triangle]
  \draw plot[samples at={0,0.5,...,6}] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))});
\end{scope}

\foreach \bb in {sine,square,ramp,sawtooth,triangle}
   \node [below,font=\footnotesize] at (\bb.south) {\bb};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To get subfigure-labels you can use `\subcaption{..}` directly in the nodes placing the labels, seeing as you're already using the `subcaption` package. Note that this requires you to set the `text width` for the node.

In the following example I add the drawing of the dotted line inside each `scope`, instead of using a loop, makes adjusting the spacing a bit easier, just change the amount of `yshift`.

I also modified the loop making the captions, to show how you can have custom texts in the captions. The screenshot is not updated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0pt} % to reduce space above subcaption
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=sine]
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,0)  -- +(6,0);
  \draw plot[domain=0:6,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))});
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3.3cm, local bounding box=square]
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,0)  -- +(6,0);
  \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,2,3}  {|- ++(1,1) |- ++(1,-2) -- ++(0,1)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-6.5cm, local bounding box=ramp]
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,0)  -- +(6,0);
  \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,2,3} {|- ++(0.25,1) |- ++(1.75,-1)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-9cm, local bounding box=sawtooth]
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,0)  -- +(6,0);
  \draw (0,-1) foreach \x in {1,2,3} {-- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,-2) };
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-12cm, local bounding box=triangle]
  \draw [densely dotted] (0,0)  -- +(6,0);
  \draw plot[samples at={0,0.5,...,6}] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))});
\end{scope}

\foreach \bb/\txt in {sine/thingamajig,square/foo,ramp/bar,sawtooth/baz,triangle/bodkin}
   \node [below,font=\footnotesize,text width=6cm] at (\bb.south) {\subcaption{\txt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{stuff}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: T.  Thanks. It works. How about if I want to label as `(a) sin, (b) square`. I tried to edit `\foreach \bb in {(a)sine,(b)square,ramp,sawtooth,triangle}` but it will not work

Comment: @aan No that won't work because `\bb` refers both to the names of the `local bounding box`es and the text in the nodes. To have different text use e.g. `\foreach \bb/\txt in {sine/(a) sine wave,square/(b) square wave,ramp/(c) rampant,sawtooth/(d) sawtooth wave,triangle/(e) triangle wave}    \node [below,font=\footnotesize] at (\bb.south) {\txt};`. I updated my answer with a different suggestion though.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add some gap between (a) and (b), it seemed that the words a little overlap

Comment: @aan The distance between each graph is determined by the `yshift` option given to the `scope` environments, so it's (almost) just a matter of changing that for the second (and third) `scope`. Because I originally used a loop to draw the dotted lines though, the y-values for the first loop would have to be adjusted accordingly. Which is a bit of a faff, so I just added a dotted line in each scope, see updated code.

Comment: Thanks, it very helpful. Just one small/last requestion. Let say I want to label  as `(a) sine (sinusoidal)` , why I cannot do that? even I had added both part `\begin{scope}[local bounding box=sine (sinusoidal)]` and `\foreach \bb in {sine (sinusoidal),square,ramp,sawtooth,triangle}`.

Comment: You probably can’t have parentheses in the names of local bounding boxes, or nodes in general. Try the loop variation in my comment above.

Comment: @aan Sorry, see I forgot to ping you in my previous comment, you may not have been notified. Anyway, I edited my second example to demonstrate how you get custom texts in the captions.

Comment: My sincere compliments (or congratulations).+1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Brillant! It works very well.